# Повторяющиеся события

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Привет всем. Помогите советом.

Есть база данных (MySQL), в которой есть таблица (events) со списком событий, имеющих дату начала (date_start) и дату завершения (date_end). Помимо этого, у некоторых событий должна быть установлена цикличность (одна и та же запись, отображающаяся несколько раз, но с разными датами. например, собрание c 12:00 до 14:00 каждую пятницу (repeat_every = 'week', repeat_day = 5) в период с 01.05.2016 (repeat_start) до 01.02.2017 (repeat_end)).

Сейчас же каждый день срабатывает крон и создает копию первоначального события за сутки до его наступления. Вопрос заключается в том, как, используя SELECT, не создавая лишних копий и с минимальными потерями в производительности, вывести события с предстоящими датами в заданном диапазоне.

Comment: Что мешает сразу при занесении записи о цикличном событии добавить необходимое количество записей - на весь период? или, если период имеет открытую дату, то до некоторой определённой в далёком будущем...

Comment: @Akina Нет, вносить заранее копии одной и той же записи не прокатит. Что ж мы будем делать, если понадобится внести изменения в цикл?

Comment: @check1st внести изменения в определение события будет значить удаление существующих записей по этому событию и создание новых. Да, это довольно большой объем работы. НО, есть принцип: оптимизировать надо то, что чаще повторяется. Так вот, чаще всего мы будем смотреть все события за некоторый период и очень редко будем править событие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(вспомогательная операция) Для реализации задачи в рамках одного запроса в нём потребуется в подзапросе генерировать таблицу с числами в количестве не меньше, чем максимально возможное количество повторов в заданном периоде. Например, если это заведомо меньше ста, то:

```
SELECT t1+10*t2 number
FROM (SELECT 0 num UNION SELECT 1 UNION ... UNION SELECT 9) t1
   , (SELECT 0 num UNION SELECT 1 UNION ... UNION SELECT 9) t2
```

==============

В основном запросе на базе таблицы шаблонов событий и подзапроса с числами на основе шаблона строим выражение расчёта даты повторения номер number, если она не вылетает за границы. Типа:

```
SELECT DATEADD(e.repeat_start, INTERVAL n.number WEEK) date
FROM events e, (подзапрос генерации чисел) n
WHERE date <= e.repeat_end
```

И... всё, собсно.

Есть, конечно, проблемы. Как минимум две.

Первая - размер периода (в показанном выше шаблоне это WEEK) нельзя просто взять из таблицы, ибо это не строковый литерал. Придётся генерировать кучу CASE-ов выбора требуемого кода в зависимости от значения repeat_every. Или для каждого значения написать свой запрос, и UNION их.

Вторая - в том, что дата начал запросто может не попадать в условие (например, при repeat_day = 5 дата в repeat_start окажется НЕ четверг). Это (поиск ближайшей даты, соответствующей условию, но больше даты начала) решается несложным выражением, опять же индивидуальным для каждого repeat_every.

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет о событиях, которые уже есть в базе данных, то можно использовать BETWEEN для выбора диапазона.
Если речь идет о событиях, которые еще не записаны в базу, то это плохой тон показывать то, чего на самом деле нет, потому что что-то может пойти не так и событие не состоится. Если все-же необходимо осуществить такую схему, используйте, например, временные таблицы.
Еще один возможный вариант - повторить логику построения задач на PHP с помощью \DateTime. Вы можете сместить, например, текущую дату на 3 дня вперед

```
$date = new \DateTime('+3 day');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Так же можно сдвинуть на неделю вперед, месяц, год, да все, что угодно. Если потребуется сдвигать N раз на один и тот же промежуток, сипользуйте цикл. Все результаты пишите в массив и его отображайте